# mysql get metadata information - user creation, user queries, user groups and database sizes

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql workbench to run my queries to interact with mysql. I have looked into "%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\" folder and found some log files that had information on mysql metadata. 

I couldn't find any log file that contains user creation log. I have found two files related to query log. One is in sql_history/date file. This contains the queries fired along with the timestamp but not the user info. Second file is log/sql_actions_unconnected.log. This too doesn't have user info.

Here are my requirements-
1. What are the users added in the last week, last month, last quarter
2. What are the top 10 users by # queries that they fire
3. What are the top 3 user groups by #users per group
4. What are the databases - top 3 ranked in highest to lowest order of size in GB

Is there any other way I could accomplish the above tasks other than relying on log files? If not how to get the above info based on log files.

Answer (score 0):

1. What are the users added in the last week, last month, last quarter

This isn't logged by default and you need to create your own mechanism. The cleanest way would be an audit plugin. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/writing-audit-plugins.html

2. What are the top 10 users by # queries that they fire

This can be queried from `sys` schema like this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.user_summary ORDER BY statements DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The `sys` schema is available with MySQL 5.7. For MySQL 5.6 it can be installed manually on top of performance_schema.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html and
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys

3. What are the top 3 user groups by #users per group

no idea what you want

4. What are the databases - top 3 ranked in highest to lowest order of size in GB

This can be found in `information_schema` like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, SUM(DATA_LENGTH) data FROM information_schema.tables GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 10;
```

But mind: This value is partly guessed. The actual disk usage can vary i.e. though fragmentation with deleted data in the pool. Docs on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html